# Untrunc / repair mp4

Tags: video, pi-4, ffmpeg

I have been trying all day to get untrunc installed on my Raspian (Pi 4) but have not made any headway.

https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc is what I've been following.  After that compile step,  I get `bash ./untrunc no such file or directory`.

I've also tried the dockerfile method but when I run the `docker run v-` line, I get an error response from daemon to pull access denied for untrunc. (That's without my changing the file paths (as I haven't figured that bit out yet)

I'm trying desperately. My daughters first Christmas videos became corrupted, I suspect the battery died during recording. FFmpeg suggest moov file is the issue.
I know that the files are salvageable as the restore. Media site can do it.

I also read about mp4box that could swap the moov and force the video file to be playable but I'm not sure how to install it or use it.

So, I found untrunc which can use a working video from the same source to repair the videos.

Sorry, noob with Linux but made the swap to a pi4 after my windows 10 laptop died.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You use `bash ./untrunc` or `./untrunc` in your command line ? It's not a shell script it's a binary file. call this with `./untrunc` in the root directory of the project. Try to set the executable rigth on the file `sudo chmod +x ./untrunc`. The file is correctly compilated and exists ? `ls -l ./untrunc`

Comment: The ./untrunc in the command line. So I don't think the file compiled correctly but following the github guide, I just assumed it would work :) no idea how to find out if the compilation failed but going by these errors I'm saying it failed.

Comment: Post an "issue" on the repository. || `bash: ./untrunc: No such file or directory` => https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc/issues/162